# How to change de document folder?

Tags: docusignapi

I have tried to change the folder where the document are stored in the E-signature API.
But when i do that the API cannot find those documents.

There is a special way to do that ?

Thank you for you responses.

Answer (score 0):

The way to move envelope is to use this API [endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/moveenvelopes/). You should be able to see the envelope in the new folder. To list folder envelopes you can use

> GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/folders/folder_id?include_items=true

What do you see if you get envelope folder information with

> GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}?include=folders